# Method to prevent infinite error with small values data prediction

Tags: standard-error, error, measurement-error

I have a series of daily data (sales) where values are low:

```
[0,1,..., 25 ]
```

These are periodic data but it has strong daily variations:

```
  10 -> 0
  0  -> 6
  ...
```

When applying a prediction model and calculate the % (MAPE), 
I get obviously very high error.

My question is :  Is there any method to remove the "divide zeros" effect, or
to deal with prediction error of small values data.
(apart from averaging the values over time, cumulative error, ...).

Answer (score 1):

You could try smoothing the MAPE value, in order to avoid this problem.

[image]

Here, the constant S works to remove the 'divide-by-zero' effect. You could tune S based on your application.

For low actual values of the target variable, S comes into play to reduce the MAPE value. Intuitively, at low values, a high percentage deviation is probably not as bad as the same percentage deviation at high values. For higher actual values, S doesn't have a large effect on the MAPE value.